# ITextSharp is not rendering images to pdf from generated from local page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using ItextSharp to generate Pdf from my aspx page. My page contains lot of images But Itext sharp is not rendering images to PDF.

I think issues is with the way downloading Html from my page. It render only Html not images because images takes time to render.

```
 protected void btnGenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
        string myPageHTML = null;
        byte[] requestHTML;
        // Gets the url of the page

        string currentPageUrl = Common.GetAppSettings("SiteURL") + "client/ClientPDFHtml.aspx";

        //UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

        // currentPageUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com"; 

        //requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData(currentPageUrl);

        //myPageHTML = utf8.GetString(requestHTML);

        System.Net.WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(currentPageUrl);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        myPageHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();



        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\outfile1.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
        hw.Parse(new StringReader(myPageHTML));
        document.Close();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=outfile.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.WriteFile(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\outfile1.pdf");
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Clear();


    }
```

Above code to request my aspx page in project which contains images.

```
<div>
    <h1 style="font-family: arial; color: #00007B; text-align: center; font-size: 34pt">
        Test Data
        <br />
        Text Paragraph</h1>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://localhost:2244/assets/images/ReportImages/image00.png"
        alt="image" height="150px" width="275px" />
</div>
```

Here is portion of html

Comment: You embedded an absolute URL to an image file in your page HTML? You know, if you ever move this site to a server instead of running it on your local PC, you'll have to update the URL? Instead, you should be using relative or root relative paths. [Here's a link](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) explaining the difference.

Comment: I am giving localhost absolute path. I also tried by giving online image path but it is not rendering images.
But if i give inline html to C# page and pass image url from there it render this properly

Comment: I think the issue you're going to face is that iTextSharp does not handle conversion of HTML to PDF seamlessly, probably because it's a bad idea to attempt anyways. Web pages are designed to be accessed from web browser. Instead, you should be building up your PDF programmatically which gives you fine grained control over the document.

Comment: @mason, absolute image paths make path resolution much easier for iTextSharp so for this specific case that is a proper solution. Also, I wouldn't go so far as to say that HTML to PDF is a bad idea. Adobe has been doing it for many years and iText has two HTML to PDF translators. If you're not willing to put in the time to learn the PDF language and/or iText's abstractions and are also willing to accept some sacrifices in control then the HTML to PDF is probably the best option.

Comment: @zubair, is the rest of your HTML (`h1` and `p`) rendering, just not images? I tried your code against this URL and it worked fine, does it not work for you? http://chris.vendiadvertising.com/test.html

Comment: Yes rest of html is working fine only issue with images.
It works fine with html written in C# string but if we try to load html from page image is not rendering only html is works fine

Comment: Did the sample URL that I provided work?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes this url works

Comment: If you can render the code in my URL to PDF but not your code then you'll need to troubleshoot what the difference is. If your local code always uses a port number try and find a way to not use it to see if that's a problem. Also, servers aren't always configured with the same DNS and firewall settings as normal computers so there's a chance that your server (and not iText) actually cannot connect to the endpoint being specified. And by "server", I'm talking about both a machine and a process that serves.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for your suggestion issue is with localhost path of images. After uploading code online all issue resolved.
Thanks all for help